# For short run-time code, better to break out early or have shorter code?

Tags: python, optimization, standards

My question pertains to short run-time code. Say, given a code that must return True or False, and two codes are as follows:

```
        **Type 1:**
    bool = False
    for item in items:
        if item (condition1):
            if item (condition2):
                 bool = True
            else:
                bool = False
     return bool  



    **Type 2:**
    bool = False
    for item in items:
        if item (condition1):
            if item (condition2):
                bool = True
            else:
                bool = False
                break  
        else: 
            bool = False
            break 
    return bool
```

If both codes are similar in run-time, which code is considered "better" or "more standard"? The first naturally does the same job as the second, but iterates over the entire object 'items'. The second exits the loop as soon as a condition is not met, and thus does the same job in more lines of code but less steps completed by the computer.

This is a simple example, but I also ask for more complex codes where the question is still the same: "Do I let it finish looping or do I break out of (possibly multiple) loops?"

Comment: Neither version looks correct.

Comment: @user2357112 I've two codes in precisely this format that both work...these are just skeletons

Comment: Well, among other problems, the first version `return`s immediately on the first iteration. It's also suspicious how you initialize `bool = False` for what looks more like an "all" check than an "any" check. That's usually the wrong thing to do.

Comment: `return items and all(condition1(i) and condition2(i) for i in items)`

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be condensed to a simple `all` call, which short-circuits (similar to the version with `break`):

```
return items and all(condition1 and condition2 for item in items)
```

The first `items` ensures that the iterable isn't empty, as, according to your code, an empty iterable would return `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking out is always better - you save time and avoid unnecessary iterations.

However, you may consider adding another `return` in the end of the function - to make sure it returns the falsy (or truthy) value when it terminates, and return only when a condition is met - otherwise you would return the value on the first iteration, like example number 1.

You should also avoid using `else`s where they add no value - they are not mandatory, just there to help you. Also, group conditions if you have no further branching - you don't need to over complicate conditions that are to be met together.

Here is how I would go with this task:

```
def foo (items):
    for item in items:
        if not item (condition1) or not item (condition2):
             return False
    return True
```

Comment: Note how your code stops on a `True`, whereas the question's Type 2 stops on a `False`. That may or may not be the correct behavior; I wouldn't trust any of the question's code to be correct.

Comment: @user2357112 It's not very clear what did OP meant the task to be, so I just made a generic example like his. but fixed anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to think of this is to weigh up which is more important for a particular project: the time of the developer, or the time of the computer?

The second choice is (slightly) more complicated to write, slightly more complicated to reason about, and potentially harder to debug. You probably only want to do this if you need to.

My rule of thumb is to write code as simply as I possibly can (which minimises the development time, and minimises the number of bugs). If the code is too slow, then I look at ways of changing the code to improve performance.